# How do I access the story mode?

Tags: pokemon-duel

So I installed Pokemon Duel, did the tutorial, etc. At some point I entered into a story mode where I keep winning in different hotels. I got out of the mode, and now have no idea how to get back!

How do I access it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it - there's an icon with six empty squares to the right of the "Play" button. If you tap that and then tap "Quests", you get the story mode for Pokemon Duel.

Reportedly after some UI changes in updates, you can press the arrow button located in the top left of the screen and hit "quest"

Answer (score 0):

If you are in version 5.0.3, press the arrow button on the top left and you can see the quest. That's the enter of the hotels.